# Show text instead of row data - PHP /MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search engine connected to a database that gives the results in a table.

Here is how table looks like: [image: How the table looks]

The column, `organizer_id` contains a number used as reference. Instead should be the organizer name.

Ex:

***1280132044***  should be ***Corporate Inc***

Can you give me a hand how to make this? I'm new in PHP/MYSQL 
Here is the code to print the results:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
   echo "<tr>\n";

   printf("<td><a href='http://embs-group.com/%s,%s'>%s</a></td>", $row['id'], str_replace(" ", "_", $row['name']), $row['name']);
   printf("<td>%s</td>", $row['organizer_id']);
   printf("<td>%s</td>", $row['no_pages']);
   printf("<td>%s</td>", $row['publication_date']);
   printf("<td>%s</td>", $row['price']);
   printf("<td>%s</td>", $row['currency']);
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
    echo "</TABLE>\n";
    }
```

Comment: this should be done with a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html) in your query part. The join should join that reference to the correct table referenced.

Comment: Umm,change $row['organizer_id'] to whatever the column where organizer name is stored is called?Show the schemas and the query part in your code.

Comment: Do you have a table with this structure organizer_id, organizer_name? Or how do you want to get the organizer name?

Comment: a have a table _reports_ and one of its columns is organizer_id, that contain the ID number of the organizer

Comment: Do you have an organizers table with the id and name of each organizer?  If so a `join` is what you are looking for...

Comment: thanks @dougjore yes, I have this table with id and name of each organizer,but how can I do the JOIN?

Comment: Please add the the sql query to your question. It´s easier to help you then.

Comment: @Henkealg Here is the code including the query 
http://pastebin.com/b14BSY2W

Comment: @PJ_ The snipplet does not show the actual sql statement for the query since it uses a compiling function (bq_simple). It´s beter if you just write the sql statement yourself and read up on how to make a join query using tutorials. There is to little details here to help you with the actual query you need.